# How to return string in java methods?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem where i am unable to return a string from this method. I was unsuccessful when I tried creating a new variable outside the Response.Listener. This is probably very simple but how do I go about returning a string from this method. The string I want to return is the 'featured_img_url' string.

```
public String secondServiceCall(String featuredmedia){

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            "http://www.gadgetsinnepal.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/"+featuredmedia, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject nested_response) {

            try {
                JSONObject guilld = nested_response.getJSONObject("guid");
                String featured_img_url = guilld.getString("rendered");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"IMAGE :" + featured_img_url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "ERROR "+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);

    return featured_img_url;
}
```

Comment: The `featured_img_url` variable only exists inside your `onResponse()` method. It does not exist inside `secondServiceCall`. When `secondServiceCall` method completes, the `onResponse()` method might not even have been called, so it is impossible to try return a variable created inside it.

Comment: So as my pals correctly said you cannot retrieve that value returning, so you should create a method that takes as parameter your variable featured_img_url and use it, this method needs to be called inside onResponse()

Comment: simple declare the string in global and update this inside onResponse.

Answer (score 0):

update your code to:

```
String featured_img_url = null;    
public String secondServiceCall(String featuredmedia){
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
        "http://www.gadgetsinnepal.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/"+featuredmedia, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject nested_response) {

        try {
            JSONObject guilld = nested_response.getJSONObject("guid");
            featured_img_url = guilld.getString("rendered");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"IMAGE :" + featured_img_url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "ERROR "+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);

return featured_img_url;
}
```

Comment: This will return the previous value or `null` if the instance never get a response. This call is asynchronous.

Comment: yeah for that you can assign some error. As if the asyncTask will not get response that will move to some another method or you can assign some default value to the variable

Comment: It doesn't work. Android studio wants to "transform 'featured_img_url' into final one element array".

Comment: declare the string outside the method.

Comment: @zovinkc, a local variable (declare in the method) need to be final to be used in a inner class. But if you set it a instance variable (so outside the methods). This works. Ankush, some error ? Unless add a lock to wait the response before ending the methods, this will not work.

Comment: @AxelH you are right the method will return the string before the request returns data.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you should simply pass the instance that call this methods to execute the methods from the response.

So change the methods to :

```
public void secondServiceCall(String featuredmedia, final MyClass caller){
```

Note that this will return nothing. And the `caller` instance need to be `final` to be used in the inner class `JsonObjectRequest`.

and in the response, you need to pass the value to the instance of `MyClass`. So add a method in `MyClass`

```
public void setFeatureImgUrl(String featuredImgUrl){ ... }
```

and you just need to call this in the response.

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject nested_response) {
    ...
    caller.setFeatureImgUrl(feature_img_url);
    ...
}
```

Note : This could be done with an Observer pattern but I know that some people doesn't like it. I could add an example of it if needed.

Comment: But I want the method to return the string at the end because there is a statement in another method that is waiting for a string result . like
sitem.img=secondServiceCall(featuredmedia)

Comment: @zovinkc You can always see how to synchronize two threads to wait for a response. But I would simply update this statement to be done in the new method ( `setFeatureImgUrl`). You can't simply return the String because this is asynchronous.

Comment: Bear with me for a second but I want to understand. Which portion is asynchronous ,is it the OnResponse method?

Comment: @zovinkc Basicly, what is happening is that you build an instance `jsonObjReq` and you push it into a `Queue` with `addToRequestQueue`. From there, the methods keeps going and end. This is an other thread that will take that request instance from the queue to execute it, it could be now, it could be in 10sec (it depends on the `Queue`). So, yes, `onReponse` is not executed in the same Thread as your `secondServiceCall` call, the full request part is done in an other thread